# How to move a RigidBody2D to a position while still checking for collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I am currently creating a game in Unity, in which you move a ball around using `OnMouseDrag()`, a `CircleCollider2D` and a `RigidBody2D`. This is how I set the position of the ball:

```
 private void OnMouseDrag()
 {
     Vector2 mouseInWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     playerRb.position = new Vector3(mouseInWorld.x, mouseInWorld.y, 0);
 }
```

I still want the ball to slide on collision while the mouse moves around. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried `RigidBody2D.MovePosition()`, but the ball jumped around from one point to another, and `Raycast`s but couldn't get that to work either.

EDIT:
This is what I've got now:

```
playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(mouseInWorld.x - playerRb.position.x, mouseInWorld.y - playerRb.position.y, 0);
```

Now the problem is, that the ball lags behind the mousePosition.

Comment: Is it a `Rigidbody` or a `Rigidbody2D`? The question includes code referring to both classes.

Comment: It's a `RigidBody2D`. Using a Vector3 for a 2D component is possible. (Don't ask why I did that though)

Comment: The Vector3 really didn't factor into the question. Using a `Rigidbody` (which your question mentioned) is also possible for 2D. This is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use RigidBody.MovePosition, you don't call the physics engine and so it ignores collisions. If you want collisions to happen you need to use RigidBody.Velocity instead.

Doing this change will require you to make some change to your code though because what you give to RigidBody.Velocity is a velocity and not a position so you will need to calculate the velocity required in x,y (and z if you are in 3d) to reach your destination.

I invite you to read the Unity page about velocity for more info
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: So directly modify the velocity?

Comment: i've edited my answer a bit but basically yes. You want to give your object a velocity directly.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I've edited my answer to reflect my new code. Now the problem is, that the ball lags behind the mousePosition.

Comment: I think you could just multiply your vector by a "speed" like
playerRb.velocity = new Vector3(mouseInWorld.x - playerRb.position.x, mouseInWorld.y - playerRb.position.y, 0) * speed
and work around that until you are satisfied. But i'm not sure it's the best solution

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it did help, but the ball was ignoring collision again.

Comment: What is your collision detection setting on your rigidbody? You should try continuous

Comment: Well maybe the speed value I entered was a little high, I've got one that works better now. I think I'll have to increase the physics timestep too.

Comment: Setting the collision detection mode helped! I'll still need to increase the timestep though, as you can see the ball bouncing of the wall for a frame.

Comment: @Schred See my answer for a solution that doesn't cause the player to bounce off the walls.

Comment: I figured out a way to combat this, by removing the bouncy physics material of the rb when it's dragged. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note: This will make the player/ball stick to collisions.

Modifying the velocity could cause the ball to bounce around unexpectedly when the ball collides with the wall. I would use a `CircleCast` for this, check if it hit anything, then use `MovePosition` accordingly:

```
float cursorDepth;
Rigidbody2D playerRb;
CircleCollider cc;

void Awake()
{
   playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   cc = GetComponent<CircleCollider>();
}

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector2 mouseInWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Vector2 posToMouse = mouseInWorld - playerRb.position;

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.CircleCast(playerRb.position, 
            cc.radius * transform.lossyScale.x, posToMouse, posToMouse.magnitude); 

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        mouseInWorld = hit.centroid;
    }

    playerRb.MovePosition(mouseInWorld);
}
```

But notice that if the ball can't move all the way to the mouse, it might cause the drag to end. So, plan accordingly.

Comment: @Schred That doesn't really describe much of how it's different from what you were looking for. I can only guess it's that you want it to slide along the walls towards the position of the mouse. Is that right?

Comment: Well, I guess, but I would've also wanted the ball to move with the mouse, like constantly, but I've got a solution that works now! It's just for a jam anyways ;)

Comment: Ah, well your question said "stuck on collision" so that sounds like you want it to stop moving when it collides. I'll change the question accordingly.